# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'! Why does my List become a NoneType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nonetype

So I'm doing this project for work. I create two lists, both made up of strings. I call the first one "wordlist_line1" and the second "titles".

```
wordlist_line1 = ["2023-06-09","EXE-shdywbedud","Heavy Circuit"]
titles = ["Time", "Device Name", "App Name"]
```

My goal is to merge the two lists into one list of tuples, where I start with an empty list

(`line1 = []`).

For example, I want this list of tuples to look something like this:

```
[("Time","2023-06-09"), ("Device Name","EXE-shdywbedud"), ("App Name", "Heavy Circuit")]
```

I tried to create this list using the following for loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(titles)):
    line1.append((titles[i], wordlist_line1[i]))
```

The problem is that the last line, where I use append(), returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 2, in <module>
    line1 = line1.append((titles[i],wordlist_text1[i]))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why is my list becoming a NoneType and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I see `wordlist_text1` and `wordlist_line1` used here, and only a definition for `wordlist_line1` - are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere?

Comment: The `.append()` method of lists doesn't return anything - it doesn't *need* to return anything, since its entire effect is the modification of the list you invoked it on.  Assigning its result back to `line1` destroyed your list.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: There is no declaration of the variable line1 in your code. Define it like this:
line1 = []
Now you should be able to append items to line1.

Comment: Don’t do `line1 = line1.append(…)`.  Just do `line1.append(…)` — OR if you really wanna do it via assignment, you can do `line1 = line1 + […]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can zip them :

```
wordlist_line1 = ["2023-06-09","EXE-shdywbedud","Heavy Circuit"]
titles = ["Time", "Device Name", "App Name"]

list(zip(titles, wordlist_line1))
```

---

your code is working fine for me:

```
line1=[]
for i in range(0,len(titles)):
    line1.append((titles[i], wordlist_line1[i]))

print(line1)
[('Time', '2023-06-09'),
 ('Device Name', 'EXE-shdywbedud'),
 ('App Name', 'Heavy Circuit')]
```

Comment: `[(x,y) for x,y in zip(titles,wordlist_line1)]` is an unecessarily verbose way of writing `list(zip(titles, wordlist_line1))`

Answer (score 0):

zip the two lists together using the zip method and pass the result into the list method to extract the tuple of lists

```
tuples = [(y, x) for x, y in zip(wordlist_line1, titles)]

tuples
```

Comment: `[(y, x) for x, y in zip(wordlist_line1, titles)]`  should just be `list(zip(titles, wordlist_line1))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes, it is the same. I also recommend this method than  list comprehension.